# Is it possible to run each thread in a separate virtual address space?

Tags: linux, multithreading, virtual-address-space

On Linux, is it possible to have threads of a process running on different virtual address spaces? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want processes instead of threads.

Comment: I think it is not possible. Anyway, can you say the reason

Comment: What's wrong with separate processes? In fact what do you want from a thread if it doesn't share its address space with its siblings?

Comment: It's neither language- nor compiler-specific question, then why did you tag it with[tag:c], [tag:c++] and [tag:gcc]?

Comment: Yeah.. threads have this big advantage - fast communication via shared buffers/queues.  Why throw that away?

Comment: @tbert: Forking generates separate processes. To be honest, I think there's a definition problem. If you create a new "thread of execution" and give it its own address space then you've created a new process by most definitions of "process" and "thread".

Comment: @CharlesBailey Yes, or, in a nutshell: "Yes, it's called forking."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although its not possible to have threads in the same process with different virtual address spaces, its still possible to have [Thread Local Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). You might be interested in that.

Answer (score 7):

**No.**  By definition, threads share an address space.  If you need separate address spaces, you should use multiple processes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.  Linux uses the [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) system call to implement threads.  The flags it takes include `CLONE_THREAD`, meaning the new process is placed in the same thread group as the calling process, and `CLONE_VM`, meaning the two processes/threads share virtual memory.  Since Linux kernel version 2.6.0-test6, you cannot specify `CLONE_THREAD` without specifying `CLONE_VM`.  (See the errors section of that link.)

However, depending on your exact motivation, you may be able to find a combination of flags for `clone` that do what you want.